# What could be the best fitted word here?

Tags: word-choice

What could be the best fitted word here?

> Is it good to keep fasting continuous days?

The word continuous might mean here everyday or a day and the other day and follow by that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simplify a bit and say:

> Is it good to fast continuously for [several] days?

**Continuous** implies the same thing as **keep** so you only need one of them and I think that **continuous** is a better option than **keep**.

Also, in this case, adding **several** helps modify **days** and can be easily replaced with any other specific number like **three** or **five**.

Additionally, "good" can be a bit vague, so you might consider rephrasing in a way that clarifies that your question is for health reasons (if it is):

> Is it healthy to fast continuously for [several] days?
>
> Will you suffer ill effects from fasting continuously for [several] days?

**Good** can imply *moral good*, as well as health, and there are many religions that use fasting as a religious observance or ritual.

Comment: yeah. "Is it healthy to fast continuously for [several] days?" explains my question well.

Answer (score 0):

You could say:

> Is it good to keep fasting continuously for days?

Since "continuous" is modifying the verb *fasting* you need to use the adverb *continuously*, not the adjective *continuous*.